# How to connect Prometheus with Presto JMX

Tags: jmx, prometheus, presto, jmx-exporter

I trying to connect prometheus with Presto jmx, I've found this exporter https://github.com/yahoojapan/presto_exporter but seems that the mentioned binaries  aren't exist.
My question is how can I create presto exporter from scratch?
and if already exist jmx_exporter can help and how ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## #1 Build from source code

You need to build the `go` code yourself

## #2 Docker (recommends)

For exmaple, where `ip` uses internal network ip so that docker container can access it.

```
# docker run --rm yahoojapan/presto-exporter:master --help
# for more infomation
docker run --rm -p 9483:9483 yahoojapan/presto-exporter:master --web.url="http://<ip>:8080/v1/cluster"
```

Then in `Prometheus`

```
scrape_configs:

  # other configurations...

  - job_name: 'presto_exporter'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['<server_ip_that_run_docker_command>:9483']
```

Restart `Prometheus`

Query `presto_*` or import this dashboard: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/10866

---

Update

There are more metrics not start with `presto_`, see: `http://<server_ip_that_run_docker_command>:9483/metrics`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Without Docker, Without presto-exporter docker container**

Prometheus monitoring also can be enabled supply JMX options in presto jvm.config file

```
-server
-Xmx3G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9015
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-javaagent:/opt/java_metrics/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=9483:/opt/java_metrics/config.yml
```

Add Prometheus scraping point for presto in `prometheus.yml` file

```
scrape_configs:

   - job_name: presto
     static_configs:
      - targets: ['<presto_ip>:9483']
```

- Presto metrics will be available at `http://<presto_ip>:9483/metrics`